# How do you set the default image in GCP?

Tags: google-compute-engine

In GCP there doesn't seem to be a setting for the default image type used during new instance creation. There also isn't a default instance type that can be set so I don't have to keep setting it every time. AWS has this feature.

Comment: If there isn't a way to set a default in the Cloud Console ... but you find that you have lots of instances to manually create, consider using the gcloud compute instances create command ... see https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create

Answer (score 1):

You can create an [instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instance-templates/create-instance-templates) which you define the machine type, boot disk image or container image, labels, and other instance properties, and then use it to create new Virtual Machine (VM) instances and managed instance groups (MIGs).

Comment: Is there a way to set the instance template as the default?

Comment: There isn't a way to set the instance template as the default, you [create a VM instance from an instance template](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/create-vm-from-instance-template#gcloud) via command is an easy way: gcloud compute instances create [INSTANCE_NAME] --source-instance-template [INSTANCE_TEMPLATE_NAME]

Answer (score 0):

Presently in GCP their is no feature for making the image and machine type as default while creating a instance machine , however it seems a really great feedback which you could provide to GCP by creating a feature request through issue tracker platform.[1]

[1] https://issuetracker.google.com/